# Can this bookmarklet be converted to Greasemonkey userscript?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, userscripts

I'm not quite sure how to convert this code from a bookmarklet to a userscript because it uses URL-encoded characters:

```
javascript:var%20multiURL="";%20$('div.titlebox').find('ul.subreddits').find('a').each(function()%20{%20multiURL%20+=%20$(this).text().substr(3)%20+%20"+";%20});%20multiURL%20=%20multiURL.substr(0,multiURL.length-1);%20window.open('http://www.reddit.com/r/'+multiURL);void(0);
```

Ideas?

Comment: http://codepad.org/xfu7CS9Q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to convert the URL-encoded characters into regular ones, which Jared Farrish has [kindly done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212957/can-this-bookmarklet-be-converted-to-greasemonkey-userscript#comment39268875_25212957)  with a bit of PHP wizardry. If you need to do this in the future, you can try this [online URL encoder/decoder](http://www.exadium.com/tools/online-url-encode-and-url-decode-tool/).

That gives you this JavaScript blob:

```
javascript:var multiURL=""; $('div.titlebox').find('ul.subreddits').find('a').each(function() { multiURL += $(this).text().substr(3) + "+"; }); multiURL = multiURL.substr(0,multiURL.length-1); window.open('http://www.reddit.com/r/'+multiURL);void(0);
```

Formatted and converted to proper JS:

```
var multiURL = "";
$('div.titlebox').find('ul.subreddits').find('a').each(function () {
    multiURL += $(this).text().substr(3) + "+";
});
multiURL = multiURL.substr(0, multiURL.length - 1);
window.open('http://www.reddit.com/r/' + multiURL);
```

Then, all that's left to do is use userscript notation and **save it in a file with a name that ends in `.user.js`** (important).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Author's Name
// @namespace      Place where file is stored
// @include        Place(s) where userscript should run
// ==/UserScript==

var multiURL = "";
$('div.titlebox').find('ul.subreddits').find('a').each(function () {
    multiURL += $(this).text().substr(3) + "+";
});
multiURL = multiURL.substr(0, multiURL.length - 1);
window.open('http://www.reddit.com/r/' + multiURL);
```

It's important to note that this will run at *every address listed with `@include`*, so you might want to consider injecting a button or something onto relevant pages so that it doesn't run unnecessarily.

Comment: The `window.open()` argument is a syntax error.

Comment: It appears that the `+` didn't carry over properly from the URL-decode: it should be fixed now.

Comment: showing error - Exception: missing ; before statement

Comment: @adi Sorry; there were more encoding errors. It should work now.